# Where does the whole email template in magento 2 being stored?

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I would like to ask if where is the email templates in magento 2 being stored. The email templates are being saved inside magento admin so I am sure that it is being stored somewhere. Either in the database o anywhere. Does somebody know how to fetch that template in magento back-end without the use of custom phtml template. Thanks!

Comment: See in Magento admin: `Marketing -> Email Templates`.

Comment: Yes. This is the page where you create or load template. But where do the saved or loaded templates are being stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All email templates are `html` files inside their module directory. You can check for  frontend email Template under

> app/code/Vendor_Module/view/frontend/email/

and for adminhtml email templates

> app/code/Vendor_Module/view/adminhtml/email/

You can edit email templates from admin panel, any template edited and saved from admin can be found under  table named `email_template` in DB.

Comment: Thank for the help. Found it.

Comment: @MiguelIntoy Glad you found it, Please mark the answer accepted if it helped you.